# Prove that if () = Θ(()), then ln(()) = Θ(ln(()))

Tags: asymptotics

Let () and () be asymptotically positive functions, and assume that lim →∞ () = ∞.  Prove that if () = Θ(()), then ln(()) = Θ(ln(()))

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your _attempts_ or _ideas_ for to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: given $C_1 $ you need to find  $C_2 $ for inequalities
$$\begin{array}{}
\ln C_1+ \ln g \leqslant C_2 \ln g \\
 C_2\ln g \leqslant \ln C_1+ \ln g 
\end{array}$$